# What is the performance impact of Firebase read/write/validate rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, query-performance

I've been reading through the Firebase documentation about security and read/write/validate rules. The documentation is pretty detailed, but I can't find any information about the performance impact security rules have on performance (querying, retrieving, writing data, etc).

For example, consider the below database example:

```
myapp : {
    projects : { 
        <project_id> : { ... }
    }
    users    : { 
        <uid> : { role : <admin or pm or other> }
    }
}
```

.. and the below database rules for reading:

```
rules : {
   projects : {
       $project : {
             {
              .read: root.child(‘users’).child(auth.uid) && root.child(‘users’).child(auth.uid).child(‘role’).val() == “admin” || root.child(‘users’).child(auth.uid).child(‘role’).val() == “pm”
                  } 
               }  
            }
```

When it comes to reading data from any $project node (ex: .child("projects/alpha).once()), what impact will this rule have on performance compared to if NO read rule existed? If I do multiple queries/reads, one after the other, will the rule get evaluated each time, or does Firebase 'save' the rule result somewhere to avoid re-evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase read and write rules are evaluated at the location where you write data or where you attach a listener. In the example you shared, you either have read permission on all project names, or you don't have permission (since [rules cannot be used to filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)). So the rule doesn't have to be evaluated for every read operation, but only when you attach the listener (or when the authentication state changes).

Given the declarative nature of the Firebase security rules, I doubt the answers to these questions affect the rules you write. They were specifically designed to be declarative for that reason: the server-side implementation can change, without changing the rules language.

You should write rules that specify *what* you want and then leave it to the Firebase Database server to decide *how* to efficiently execute them. If you ever encounter a case where you think your rules are making a read or write slow, I'd love to see *that* in a question.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the quick reply. As a follow up, what effect does having a rule vs. not having a rule have on performance? Is it essentially negligible? (I've made some edits to the question to be more clear).

Comment: Unless you're having a performance problem that you think is caused by specific rules, I'd stick to writing the rules that fit your use-case. Anything else is premature optimization.